# what is exact meaning smtp_receive_timeout in exim.conf?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, exim

what is the exact meaning of smtp_receive_timeout in exim.conf ?

Is it timeout for receiving the data after rcpt to ?
Or is the total timeout for complete receiving a mail data ?

Or If there is no communication for that duration, the connection will be closed ?

Please kindly explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

> **smtp_receive_timeout**    **Use: main**    **Type: time**    **Default: 5m**
>
> This sets a
> timeout value for SMTP reception. It applies to all forms of SMTP
> input, including batch SMTP. If a line of input (either an SMTP
> command or a data line) is not received within this time, the SMTP
> connection is dropped and the message is abandoned. A line is written
> to the log containing one of the following messages:
>
> SMTP command timeout on connection from... SMTP data timeout on
> connection from... The former means that Exim was expecting to read an
> SMTP command; the latter means that it was in the DATA phase, reading
> the contents of a message.
>
> If the first character of the option is a “$” the option is expanded
> before use and may depend on $sender_host_name, $sender_host_address
> and $sender_host_port.
>
> The value set by this option can be overridden by the -os command-line
> option. A setting of zero time disables the timeout, but this should
> never be used for SMTP over TCP/IP. (It can be useful in some cases of
> local input using -bs or -bS.) For non-SMTP input, the reception
> timeout is controlled by receive_timeout and -or.

But to understand this more you must read this
http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html